# Two equivalent definitions of a tangent space of manifold

Tags: calculus, manifolds

> Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^N $ be an $n$ dimensional manifold. We define the tangent space of $M$ at a point, say $0$, to be: $$ T_{p}M=\phi'|_{x_{0}}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right) $$
> Where $phi$ is a chart $ \mathbb{R}^{n}\supset\mathcal{U}_{x}\overset{\phi}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal{U}\subset M$, and $\mathcal{U}$ is an open neighborhood of the point $0 \in M$ such that $\phi(x_0) =0$.
> Also, by $ \phi'|_{x_{0}}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right) $ I mean the image of $\mathbb{R}^n$ under the linear transformation $ \phi'|_{x_{0}} $ which can be represented by $N\times n $ matrix.

I've read about manifolds in another book, and I saw a different definition:

> Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^N $ be a manifold. Then we define the tangent space at the point $0\in M $ to be: $$ T_{0}M:=\left\{ \frac{d}{dt}x\left(t\right)|_{t=0}\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace:\thinspace\thinspace x\left(t\right)\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\text{is a parametrized curve }\left(\mathbb{R},0\right)\ni t\longrightarrow x\left(t\right)\in\left(M,0\right)\right\}  $$
> Where $(\mathbb{R},0)$ and $(M,0)$ means "small" neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ or $M$ respectively (a germ).

How can I show those definitions are equivalent? i.e, how can I show that:

$$ \phi'|_{x_{0}}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)\equiv\left\{ \frac{d}{dt}x\left(t\right)|_{t=0}\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace:\thinspace\thinspace x\left(t\right)\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\text{is a parametrized curve }\left(\mathbb{R},0\right)\ni t\longrightarrow x\left(t\right)\in\left(M,0\right)\right\}  $$

**Note**

The choice of the char $\phi $ does not change the tangent space (I have proved already).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The idea is the following: for any parametrized curve $x(t)$ on the manifold passing through $0$ you can use the cart $\phi$ to obtain a curve $\phi^{-1}\circ x (t)$ passing thru $x_0$ on the coordinate domain $\mathcal{U}_x\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. This curve "in parameter space" has a derivative at $t=0$ that will get mapped to $x'(0)$ via $\phi'|_{x_0}$. This construction can be easily reversed.

Comment: @topolosaurus Thanks, indeed it solves one direction easily, but I find the other direction more difficult, given a vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$, how can I prove that $\phi'|_{x_{0}}v $ is the derivative of some parametrized curve which lies in the manifold? I need to define this curve somehow, but not sure how to gurantee existance of such curve

Comment: Sure! Take the following curve $\beta:t\mapsto x_0 + t v$ for $|t|<\epsilon$, $\epsilon$ small enough so that $\beta(t)\in\mathcal{U}_x$ for all such $t$. Then clearly $\beta'(0)=v$, and $x(t)=\phi\circ \beta (t)$ is the curve on the manifold that you are looking for.

Comment: @topolosaurus I see. That was my intuition too, to define such a curve, but it seemed too arbitrary, I mean, what about $\beta :t\to x_0 + t^2v $, would it work too? should'nt it be unique?

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is $0$-dimensional, it must be a discrete metric space, and thus any curve on $M$ must in fact be constant (else it would be disconnected), so we can pretty easily compute that both sets are equal to $\{0\}$ (where this is the $0$ in $\mathbb R^n$).

Going forward, I'm going to call the point on the manifold $z$ to not confuse with the $0$ in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^N$. The proof is by double containment.

First, suppose $v\in T_p M$, and by the openness of $\mathcal U_x$ pick $r>0$ with $B(x_0,r)\subseteq U_x$. Picking $h\in \mathbb R^n$ with $v=D\phi(x_0)h,$ we can define the curve $\gamma:(-r/(1+|h|),r/(1+h))\to \mathcal U$ via $\gamma(t)=\phi(x_0+th)$. We can easily compute that $\gamma(0)=z$ and thus $\gamma'(0)=D\phi(x_0)h=v$, so $v\in T_0M$ as well.

Conversely, let $v\in T_0M$, and fix such a curve $\gamma:(a,b)\to \mathcal U$ with $0\in (a,b)$, $\gamma(0)=z$, and $\gamma'(0)=v$. Our goal is to reverse the above construction. In particular, if the function $\phi^{-1}\circ \gamma$ were differentiable, then by the chain rule we could take
$$\gamma'(0)=(\phi\circ \phi^{-1}\circ \gamma)'(0)=D\phi(\phi^{-1}(\gamma(0)))D\phi^{-1}(\gamma(0))\gamma'(0)$$
Calling $h:=D\phi^{-1}(\gamma(0))\gamma'(0)\in\mathbb R^N$ and noting that $\phi^{-1}(\gamma(0))=x_0$, we would have $v=\gamma'(0)=D\varphi(x_0)h$, so $v\in T_pM$.

Of course, it is meaningless to consider the derivative of $\phi^{-1}$ directly, as it is not defined on an open set. To account for this, we can invoke the fact that there exists a "local flattening map" $F:\mathcal U\to F(\mathcal U)\subseteq \mathbb R^N$ with $(F_1,\dots,F_n)=\phi^{-1}$ and replacing every instance of $D\phi^{-1}$ above with $DF$.

By double containment, we're done.

(Let me know if there are any confusions/mistakes surrounding notation or steps of the argument. I am currently learning this material myself with different notation, so if there are bits that I can clarify I'd be happy to do so.)